# Should I close a question if I have limited knowledge of that domain?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

While reviewing close votes in review queue, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428345/how-to-setting-proxy-in-python-scrapy) appeared to me for review.

This question linked above has [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy) tags added to it. Truly speaking, I don't have any experience or domain knowledge of both of them.

However, before me, there were 4 close votes already on this post referencing to a duplicate question.

From the description of the question and title of the referenced dupe, it appears to me as well that it seems a duplicate. However, in case if there were no close votes on that question, I'm not able to find out that this post is a duplicate of another post or not...

So, following 2 factors forced me to close this question:

1. Description of this question and title of referenced duplicate seems relevant.
2. Significant(4) close votes are already referencing to another post.

Is it acceptable to close such a post with the scenario described above? Or I should let it go without doing anything?

Comment: If you can't judge a review use skip, there is [no shame in doing that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip). Also know that you can [filter on tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlo7o.png) in the close vote queue. I'm sure there are enough reviews in html/css/javascript to handle.

Comment: *Do not* vote to close just because 3 or 4 others did the same. Review is for *reviewing questions*, not following other reviewers blindly.

Comment: How do you know that the second vote wasn't following the first one, just like you thought to follow the fourth one?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Your point is absolutely right, but vote count is not the only factor here. As I stated, referenced question also gave some information.

Comment: Sometimes (but probably not for this specific question) the difference between _being a duplicate_ and _looking [a bit] like a duplicate_ does depend on subtleties that only come with deeper knowledge of the subject area. Without that domain knowledge -- as others have said -- it's probably best to skip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are an unlimited amount of posts awaiting you in the close vote review queue. If it is not evident which action to take on a given edge case (or in this scenario where it requires domain knowledge), then simply skip and happily find the next 1/∞ waiting for you instead.

Comment: Ok @Travis Thanks for answer and best of luck for your success in moderator elections.